# Find unique numbers in array

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, numbers

Well, I have to find how many different numbers are in an array.

For example if array is: 1 9 4 5 8 3 1 3 5

The output should be 6, because 1,9,4,5,8,3 are unique and 1,3,5 are repeating (not unique).

So, here is my code so far..... not working properly thought.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int r = 0, a[50], n;
    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> a[i];
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < j; k++) {
            if (a[k] != a[j]) r++;
        }
    }
    cout << r << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sort the array, then it's trivial. Try to figure out for yourself how the complexity of that compares to the complexity of your solution.

Comment: This seems like homework to me... but yes, you can sort the array, or you can use a hashtable.

Comment: seems SO is a good place to get last minute homework done.  format question, post it on SO, ???, get answer!

Comment: @thang: Seems it's not - considering that nearly all answers to this questions have either an incorrect algorithm or use the standard library to do the job - which apparently is not what this homework is about ...

Comment: This is the best logic I ever found.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28320454/can-xor-of-two-integers-go-out-of-bounds

Answer (score 14):

Let me join the party ;)

You could also use a hash-table:

```
#include <unordered_set>
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    int a[] = { 1, 9, 4, 5, 8, 3, 1, 3, 5 };
    const size_t len = sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]);

    std::unordered_set<int> s(a, a + len);

    std::cout << s.size() << std::endl;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}
```

Not that it matters here, but this will likely have the best performance for large arrays.

---

If the difference between smallest and greatest element is reasonably small, then you could do something even faster:

- Create a [`vector<bool>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t0723a54.aspx) that spans the range between min and max element (if you knew the array elements at compile-time, I'd suggest the `std::bitset` instead, but then you could just compute everything in the compile-time using template meta-programming anyway).
- For each element of the input array, set the corresponding flag in `vector<bool>`.
- Once you are done, simply count the number of `true`s in the `vector<bool>`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, although this is not very basic, I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 11):

A `std::set` contains only unique elements already.

```
#include <set>

int main()
{
    int a[] = { 1, 9, 4, 5, 8, 3, 1, 3, 5 };

    std::set<int> sa(a, a + 9);
    std::cout << sa.size() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: is "9" the number of entries or the highest value?

Comment: @Ben no, it's the size of an array

Answer (score 4):

How about this?

```
#include <list>

int main()
{
    int a[] = {1, 9, 4, 5, 8, 3, 1, 3, 5};

    std::list<int> la(a, a+9);
    la.sort();
    la.unique();
    std::cout << la.size() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You also could have used `std::set` :P

Comment: Well, my problem is that I haven't studied vectors yet and I have to make this using loops / arrays only. Any help with that?

Comment: You need to sort it first, then count adjacent elements.

Comment: Is the correctness of the la.unique() method predicated on firstly running sort()?

Answer (score 1):

Since you've stated that you cannot use the standard library and must use loops, let's try this solution instead.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std; // you're a bad, bad boy!

int main() 
{
    int r = 0, a[50], n;

    cout << "How many numbers will you input? ";
    cin >> n;

    if(n <= 0)
    {
        cout << "What? Put me in Coach. I'm ready! I can do this!" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    if(n > 50)
    {
        cout << "So many numbers! I... can't do this Coach!" << endl;
        return -1;
    }   

    cout << "OK... Enter your numbers now." << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cin >> a[i];


    cout << "Let's see... ";

    // We could sort the list but that's a bit too much. We will choose the
    // naive approach which is O(n^2), but that's OK. We're still learning!

    for (int i = 0; i != n; i++) 
    { // Go through the list once.      
        for (int j = 0; j != i; j++)
        { // And check if this number has already appeared in the list:
            if((i != j) && (a[j] == a[i]))
            { // A duplicate number!        
                r++; 
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    cout << "I count " << n - r << " unique numbers!" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I *urge* you to *not* submit this code as your homework - at least not without understanding it. You will only do yourself a disservice, and chances are that your instructor will know that you didn't write it anyways: I've been a grader before, and it's fairly obvious when someone's code quality magically improves.

Comment: This solves a different problem: it counts the values that occur exactly once, not all different values.

Comment: @joergb You are wrong. Read the code again - and tell me what `n - r` calculates. It's really not difficult to figure it out; you can even *run* the code if you must.

Comment: I read the code again, I now even ran it against the test input of the OP: with that input it returns `3`, not `6` as for the specified problem. It is as I said: your code counts numbers that occur only once. `r` counts all instances of numbers that occur repeatedly - even the first. The OP wanted a count of *all* different numbers. The solutions using std::set or std:: list get that right.

Comment: Oh wow, you're right. I totally misread the problem. Will tweak the code.

Answer (score 0):

I think the location for increasing the value of r is incorrect

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int r=0,a[50],n;
    cin >>n;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cin >> a[i];
    }
    for (int j=0;j<n;j++)
    {   
        bool flag = true;  
        for(int k=;k<j;k++)
        {
            if(a[k]!=a[j])
            {
               flag = false;
               break;
            }
       }
       if (true == flag) 
       {
           r++;
       }
    }
    cout << r << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

However, my suggestion is using more sophisticated algorithms (this algorithm has O(N^2)).

Comment: O(n^2) complexity *and* `if (true == flag)`? The latter is particularly scary.

Comment: No, I meant, can't you figure out why it's not working as intended?

Comment: Not really, especially with booleans I got even more confused.

Comment: The problem is not in the booleans. It is in the main condition. If you rename `flag` to have a name that tells what it means, you might spot it.

Answer (score 0):

this should work, however its probably not the optimum solution.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int a[50],n;        
int uniqueNumbers; // this will be the total numbers entered and we will -- it
cin >>n;    
uniqueNumbers = n;  
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    cin >> a[i];
}   
for (int j=0;j<n;j++)
{   
    for(int k=0;k<n;k++)
    {
        /* 
        the and clause below is what I think you were missing.
        you were probably getting false positatives when j == k because a[1] will always == a[1] ;-)
        */
        if((a[k] == a[j]) && (k!=j)) 
        { uniqueNumebers--; }
    }       
}
cout << uniqueNumbers << endl;
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use C++ STL vector in this program .

```
  int main() 
  {
    int a[] = {1, 9, 4, 5, 8, 3, 1, 3, 5};
    vector<int>v(a, a+9);

    sort(v.begin(), v.end()); 
    v.erase(unique(v.begin(), v.end()), v.end()); 

    cout<<v.size()<<endl;

    return 0;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please dry run your code 
See in the outer for loop for each element it is counted more than one inside inner loop.let us say the loop contains 1,2,3,4.1.....elements dry run it in the second iteration and third iteration  1 is counted because 1 is 1!=2 as well as 1!=3

Now solution time!!

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
#define ll long long
using namespace std;
ll arr[1000007]={0};
int main()
{
  ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);//used for fast i/o
    ll n;cin>>n;
      for(ll i=1;i<=n;i++)
        cin>>arr[i];

        sort(arr,arr+n);

       ll cnt=0;
                for(ll i=1;i<=n-1;i++)
                  {
                   if(arr[i+1]-arr[i]==0)
                     cnt++;
                  }
                 cout<<n-cnt<<endl;


  cin.tie(NULL);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not as graceful as using set but works 1.4 times faster

```
int a[] = {1, 9, 4, 5, 8, 3, 1, 3, 5}

std::map<int, char> m;

for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    if ( m.count(a[i]) == 0 )
        m.insert( pair<int, char>(a[i], 0x00) );
}
```

Keys in map `m` presents list of unique values in array `a`

Answer (score -1):

#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

```cpp
int find_unique(int arr[], int size){

    int ans = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        ans = ans^arr[i];  // this is bitwise operator .its call XOR  it's return only unique value..  

    }

    return ans;
}
```

```cpp
void print_array(int arr[], int size){
    
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

```cpp
int main()
{
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false); cin.tie(NULL);  // use for fast input and output....

    int arr[5] = {1, 3, 5, 3, 1};

    cout <<"Orginal array: " << endl;
    print_array(arr, 5);
    int result = find_unique(arr, 5);
    cout << result << endl;

    return 0;
}
```