# C++ left shift overflow for negative numbers

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

As shown below, the code has a bug. When input a = -1, b = 1, one of the line has runtime error. Could you please help me understand how (a & b) becomes INT_MIN?

In my understanding, -1 is represented as 32-bit binary format 0xFFFFFFFF, and 1 is represented as 32-bit format 0x00000001, thus (-1 & 1) will become 0x00000001. And my python command also shows '0b1' as result. Why does it report the error of INT_MIN?

```
int getSum(int a, int b) {
    while (b != 0) {
        int carry = (a & b) << 1;//BUG! left shift of negative value -2147483648
        a = a ^ b;
        b = carry;
    }

    return a;
}
```

Update: Is right shift for negative numbers well-defined? It seems ok to right shift negative numbers as long as it satisfies the requirements as quoted below.

From cppreference.com,

> For unsigned a and for signed a with nonnegative values, the value of
>   a >> b is the integer part of a/2b . For negative a, the value of a >>
>   b is implementation-defined (in most implementations, this performs
>   arithmetic right shift, so that the result remains negative).
>
> In any case, if the value of the right operand is negative or is
>   greater or equal to the number of bits in the promoted left operand,
>   the behavior is undefined.

Comment: We aware that exists more than one way to represent a negative number in binary, not only 0xFFFFFFFF

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations

Comment: note that XOR doesn't produce more bits than the operands, so it can never overflow (except probably on systems with trap representation) [Can XOR of two integers go out of bounds?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28320454/995714). INT_MIT is well within `int`'s range, therefore it's not an overflow

Comment: The first `a & b` is `1` as you say, but you are in a `while` loop that updates the values of `a` and `b`, the bug comes on a later iteration

Comment: for bit-twiddling one uses *unsigned types* in C.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming this is C or C++, your error is because a [Left Shifting a negative value is Undefined Behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3784996/10396), and left shifting a signed value such that it becomes bigger than MAX_INT is also Undefined Behavior.

If you inspect the values of `a` and `b` as you run through this sequence, you will get:

```
-1 1
-2 2
-4 4
...
-1073741824 1073741824
```

At this point `a&b == 1073741824`.  But shifting it left by 1 is the same as multiplying by 2, which would give `2147483648`, which is larger than INT_MAX.

That's Undefined Behavior. The system can choose to do anything. It appears that in your case, it did the bitshift giving `0x80000000`. In a signed `int`, this represents INT_MIN.  So the next time through the loop, you are trying to left shift a negative number, which again is Undefined Behavior. Your system chose to treat this as an exception.

In general, if you are doing bit-manipulations, you are best using unsigned types.

Comment: Thanks a lot! In this case, when a = -1 and b = 1, how shall we handle the left shift? Essentially, the getSum() function is calculating a + b with bit manipulation.

Comment: cast to unsigned.

Comment: Thanks, could you please explain a bit more details?